# Почему терминал в macOS не выводит русские символы? Исправления, как на windows не работают в терминале мака

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, macos

Следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;
    string str;
    cout << "Введите строку: " << endl;
    cin >> str;
    int l = str.size();
    cout << l << " " << str << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
        cout << str[i] << " ";


    return 0;
}
```

должен считывать строку, посчитать кол-во символов в ней и вывести их через пробел, если строка вводится на английском, то всё работает корректно, если на русском, то получается:

```
Подберёзовик
24 Подберёзовик
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? Process exited with status 0
```

Comment: В этом цикле выводятся не символы, а байты. Там почти наверняка используется кодировка UTF-8 где символы переменной длины. Хочется работать с юникодом - ставьте библиотеку ICU. Ну или самостоятельно напишите алгоритм итерации, благо он не сложный.

Comment: как поставить ее на с++?